# Save iwconfig to a variable

Tags: bash, conky

I am trying to assign Link Quality (percentage) from `iwconfig` to a variable in a `.sh` file. This is for a conky theme I'm making. To do this I have the following:

```
lnk=$(iwconfig mlan0 | awk '/Link Quality/{split($2,a,"=|/");print int((a[2]/a[3])*100)}')
```

This command works if I enter it at the command line. However, in the script file it does not work or at least it doesn't seem to. I can put `echo $lnk` right after and it returns nothing. The real kicker is, this was working before, but I changed distributions from Mint to MX Linux. I don't know how much that would affect anything but it's the only change I've made before this stopped working.

The other thing is, I also use a very similar script that was based on this one for battery level. It works great. But I can't understand why this one all of a sudden doesn't work anymore.

***UPDATE*** - While I haven't yet figured out what was wrong, I did find a work-around. Instead of using a .sh file to get the information I wanted and manipulating it from there, I just decided to do it directly in the conky template. There's always more than one way to get the desired output.

Thanks anyway for what it's worth.

Comment: Are you sure your wireless interface name is mlan0?

Comment: Yes I am 100% certain that is the interface name. There are other functions that list other statistics from the interface and they use the same device name and work fine.

@RuiFRibeiro, apologies for the title. I should have made it more relevant to the topic.

Comment: You write that you use a `.sh` file. Are you sure it is executed in `/bin/sh`, and not in `bash`, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Does classic **Bourne shell's *backtick*-based construct** work?

Like following script...

```
#!/bin/sh
LINK_Q="`iwconfig mlan0 | awk '/Link Quality/{split($2,a,"=|/");print int((a[2]/a[3])*100)}')`"
echo "$LINK_Q"
```

If it doesn't, do you have a way to know which exact brand and version of shell that Conky used for running the script?

P.S. If you changed GNU/Linux distribution, also double-check the interface name.